# Arrango DB Power BI connector - 503 issue

Tags: powerbi, arangodb

We have been using the Arrango DB for a while. As per the recent requirement, we are developing Dashboards Power BI. As per the instructions in the Power Bi - Arrango DB interaction Guide we have created connectors and are able to access the data. But after certain days(roughly 30 days of usage) when we are receiving the error "(503): Service Unavailable" when trying to connect to the Connector. We tried creating a new connector but after a few days, we have encountered a similar issue.

We are unable to understand the root cause for the issue. For working with dashboards we can create new connectors but it is quite not easy to update the data source in all the dashboards. We are not sure if the issue linked with Powe Bi releases

FYI:: we also have tried re-creating the connector with the same configuration of an issue connector. But still, we get 503 error

Tools:

- Arrango DB 3.8.0 Community edition
- Power BI Desktop Version: 2.98.1025.0 64-bit (October 2021)

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need any information from our end.

Comment: This is not a programming question and as stated it is not possible to give a correct answer without a lot of guessing. I suggest to ask this question in the slack-community (https://arangodb-community.slack.com)

Comment: @TomRegner, Thanks for sharing the information. Could help me with how can I join the group. Is there an invitation link?

Comment: No, you just register with your preferred email-address for this issue (work address probably) here https://slack.com/get-started#/find, and then search/join the arangodb-community workspace.

Comment: Recently we are able to find solve this problem. The root cause of the issue is the change in the name of the collections, the code of the connector checks the existence of all the collections defined in the list and if the collection is missing then we get the 503 Service unavailable. So even a small change in the collection name spelling (even the case) might trigger this error.

Comment: Would you post this outcom/solution as an answer and accept it? Easier to find the cause in an answer than a comment :), and this could happen to others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Recently we are able to find solve this problem. The root cause of the issue is the change in the name of the collections, the code of the connector checks the existence of all the collections defined in the list and if the collection is missing then we get the 503 Service unavailable. So even a small change in the collection name spelling (even the case) might trigger this error.